# Animation in seekbar to go to initial point once thumb is dragged to its end

Tags: android, seekbar

how to animate the seekbar so that it one drags the thumb to seekbar max value the thumb automatically goes back to initial point.I am a begginer so plz if possible give a elaborated answer

```
sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                                int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                            value = sb.getProgress();

                            if (value == 50) {
                                Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(
                                        R.drawable.off);
                                sb.setThumb(drawable);

                            } 
                            ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(seekBar.getProgress(),0);
                            anim.setDuration(1000);
                            anim.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                                int animProgress = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                                sb.setProgress(animProgress);
                                }
                            });
                            anim.start();

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Pallavi, you can do this, programatically. When seekbar reached at max limit, just inflate your seekbar again to min limit.

Comment: but i want that where ever i drag the thumb it should more back to its initial value

Comment: didnt get you? can you please post your code here or can you please explain me proper with example?

Comment: i meant that if in whichever position(20% or 100% i.e max value drag my thumb the thumb should automatically come back to its minimum value

Comment: ok, can you please show me your code ?

Comment: this is the code but not working

Comment: You are doing animation with seekbar progres changed right?

Comment: if u have understood my prob plz help

Comment: Its still confusing pallavi, can you please send me your code on my email?

Comment: can i have your email id

Comment: sorry pratik for the inconvinience but i dont understand what u mean to say if u can provide me with your gmail i will mail u and i have posted the code with the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the answer to my question. If anyone one need it, then it is....

```
SeekBar sb;
ValueAnimator anim;
int value;
sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
            int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        value = sb.getProgress();
        ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(value,
                sb.getMax());
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(
                    ValueAnimator animation) {
                value = (Integer) animation
                        .getAnimatedValue();
                sb.setProgress(value);
            }
        });
        anim.start();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,
                        sb.getMax());
                anim.setDuration(1000);
                anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(
                            ValueAnimator animation) {
                        value = (Integer) animation
                                .getAnimatedValue();
                        value = 100 - value;
                        sb.setProgress(value);
                    }
                });
                anim.start();
            }
        }, 1200);
    }
});
```